# What is the most efficient way to create a kotlin.String from a range of a ByteArray?

Tags: kotlin

In Java you have:

```java
byte[] bytes = ...
int pos = ...
int length = ...
new String(bytes, pos, length)
```

This will create one additional `byte[]` internally in `String`.

What is the most efficient way to do that in Kotlin (i.e. with the least amount of additional objects)?

```kotlin
val bytes : ByteArray = ...
val pos : Int = ...
val length : Int = ...
???
```

Comment: Your question is a little enigmatic on whether you look for a way to do this with the same performance as in Java or you look for a more performant way. You can do exactly the same as in Java and this is the best you can get.

Comment: @broot Thanks. I'm targeting  JVM and now that I have retried the conversion from the Java file, I get `kotlin.String` again. After removing the `kotin.`-prefix I can confirm that Navigate|Declaration or Usage takes me to Kotlin's `fun String(...)`. Yesterdays I'm pretty sure it took me to `java.lang.String` (maybe by some back and forth I had messed up the imports). Either way, everything fine now.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Anyway, it looks like some kind of a bug in the Java->Kotlin conversion util. It shouldn't behave like that.

Comment: @broot I have reported this problem now: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-312974

Answer (score 0):

```
val bytes: ByteArray = ByteArray(10) { ('a'..'z').toList()[it].code.toByte() }
val pos: Int = 3
val length: Int = 4

val result = String(bytes.sliceArray(pos until pos + length))
```

Comment: I imagine this was downvoted because bytes.sliceArray creates an extra intermediate byte array. Better to just call `String(bytes, offset, length)` (or the overload that takes a charset, if not UTF-8)